# Opscenter 4.1 can't add cluster

Tags: cassandra

When trying to add an existing cluster to Opscenter via the 'add cluster' gui screen I am getting the following error:

Error creating cluster: OpsCenter was able to get the cluster name but not list the available keyspaces. This may indicate an authentication problem. The error from Cassandra was: You have not logged in

The cassandra cluster was started with user authenticator set to PasswordAuthenticator.  DBA users were created and are working fine via cqlsh.  Is there a particular user Opscenter uses and where is that user's password set?

Cassandra 2.0.4  Opscenter 4.1 Linux package installation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

On the form where you enter connection information about your cluster (eg, list of hosts to connect to), there is an "Add Credentials" link.  If you click that link, you can enter a thrift username & password, which will allow OpsCenter to connect to your cluster.